# Sonar java vulnerability method return true

Tags: java, ssl, sonarqube

Below is my code snippet for SSL Hostname verifier. But As I am returning unconditional `true` from this method. This is countered as a vulnerability by sonar. How I will resolve this one?

```
SslClient sslClient = SslClient.localhost();
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslClient.socketFactory;
    HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
      @Override public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
      }
    };
```

I want to know the best way.

Comment: By not writing a vulnerable method like that. You can either fix your method so you are not returning true regardless of a hostname verification or mark is as Wont Fix

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to return true unconditionally? If that's the vulnerability detected by Sonar, you should either not do it, or document why it is actually safe in this case.

In terms of implementing "some" fix, [look at the test cases](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/test/files/checks/security/HostnameVerifierImplementationCheck.java) for the class. It seems that the implementation it wants you to use is:

> ```
> @Override
>   public boolean verify(String a, SSLSession b) {
>     return a.equalsIgnoreCase(b.getPeerHost());
>   }
> ```

Comment: You should read the [rule description](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Vulnerability/RSPEC-3510) instead and double check that the code in the "compliant solution" section makes sense in your case (don't copy-paste code blindly!). The test cases of the rules are certainly not intended to show developers how they should code.